# Abort the Jenkins build inside the bash step

Tags: bash, jenkins

How to immediately fail/abort the build if the server is pinging, and if not than proceed the build. I have the following bash step, but it's now working properly.

```
#!/bin/sh
  if
    ping -c 1 $VmIP &> /dev/null
  then
    echo "--------HOST pinging aborting the build----------"
    exit 1
  else 
    echo "Not pinging, proceed"
  fi
```

It is exited the build even if server is not pinging. But should abort when server is pinging

Comment: how is it working and how do you want it to work ?

Comment: It is exited the build even if server is not pinging. But should abort when server is pinging

Comment: `I have the following bash step, but it's now working properly` - so is it working? `It is exited the build even if server is not pinging. But should abort when server is pinging` - This sentence is not really making sense, can you rephrase it or correct the grammer?

Answer (score 0):

In your bash script, you only have to run your check then set the exit status.

Using Jenkins pipeline, you can get the exit status of your bash script then set the value of `currentBuild.result` accordingly:

```
stage ('Ping') {
    steps {
        script {
            exit_status = sh(script: "<RUN YOUR SCRIPT>", returnStatus: true)
            if (exitStatus != 0) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'` will abort the remaining stages.